# How would one design a flow where one of the screens is a login screen?

Tags: android

I am writing an Android app which requires the user to be logged in. I have a main Activity, and I want that when the app launches, that it takes the user to a login screen if they are not already logged in.

How should I model this? Is the login page another Activity? I'm thinking not because I don't want the user to be able to get back there using the back button. Or is there a way to replace an activity with another so the back button problem doesn't happen?

Or, should I have just one activity and load in a login view and swap it out once the user logs in?

Are there any best practices around this?

Thanks!

Comment: See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41290453/4560689

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check on the main or splash screen to check if the user is logged in, if not start the login activity.

Once the login completes, in the login activity, call [this.finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

If you need to change activities, you can call .finish() followed by starting whatever activity you wanted.

If getting back to the splash/main screen without being logged in is a problem, you can do the same thing there.

Answer (score 2):

For this ask "I'm thinking not because I don't want the user to be able to get back there using the back button"

The answer is using the attribute noHistory in your Login Activity, like the example:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"...
```

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the login screen is an another activity. The back key problem is solved with onKeyDown() method of that activity. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29).
The whole flow can be imagined like this:

You're starting your app. The main activities check for login flag(in shared preferences or somewhere else). If user has logged in, then the main activity stays on the screen. If not, activity starts login activity using intent. Login activity performs the logging in and sets the login flag and start the main activity again.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, but I don't quite understand how this relates? The LoginActivity will register the callback? If I'm on the main page, after just having logged in, will pressing back send the key event to the LoginActivity?

Comment: @lowellk: Use splash activity to check whether user logs in or not. From thr u can navigate to ur required activity.

Comment: Vladamir, what do you mean by starting the main activity again? Is the login page going to manually launch the main activity? Or is it going to go 'back' to the main activity? If it's going back, does that mean it should use startActivityForResult?

Comment: fargath, I don't understand how that solves the back button problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a dialog for the login? I suppose what you could do is have the first Activity check at onCreate() using SharedPreferences if the user has already logged in, and if she hasn't then it generates the dialog. After logging in the dialog would change a variable which would be passed to SharedPreferences so that the user won't have to relogin if the screen orientation changes or the app pauses.

Comment: Hmm, a dialog could work. I got it working as an Activity, though, so I'm just going to stick with that.