# Android User Registration

Tags: php, android, authentication, registration

I'm toying with Android at the moment as a learning experience and one of the things i'd like to do is make a basic app that when the app is launched for the first time the user is requested to register/login, these registration details are then stored online so that the user can go to the website and login using them details.

Now am i right in assuming i can somehow just POST the username and password to the registration script i have, e.g. mywebsite.com/register.php or login.php?

Does anyone have any resources for doing a register / login style splash screens - i've searched high and low and haven't had too much luck so far.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126406/how-would-one-design-a-flow-where-one-of-the-screens-is-a-login-screen.

Comment: @Ted Hopp I'm more getting at the stage of posting to php / getting a response rather than modelling the splash / login screen and the associated complexities (as the above link is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Post the username and password, and have your php script insert or do whatever you need to with the database, and return whatever data.