# What is the correct way of creating a login screen/activity in Android?

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity

I am working on an Android application that requires a user to login before doing anything else. Currently I have created main Activity named LoginScreen and upon successful login this activity launches another Activity called Home. But I see a problem with this approach. What if user presses back button from Home activity? I dont want user going back to login screen. what is the correct way of stopping the user from doing that. Do I need to handle Key Press events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would one design a flow where one of the screens is a login screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126406/how-would-one-design-a-flow-where-one-of-the-screens-is-a-login-screen)

Comment: https://github.com/adityasd/LoginDemo

Answer (score 54, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to make my Home activity handle the intent **android.intent.action.MAIN**. Home activity, when launched, checks if the user is signed in or not (using shared preferences), if its not then it starts LoginActivity and calls finish() on its self.

LoginActivity on successful login starts the Main activity and this time because the user is logged on, the Main activity will continue its normal course. LoginActivity is declared as following in the manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="LoginScreen" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true" android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

Setting noHistory and excludeFromRecents to true for LoginActivity means that the user cant return to this activity using back button.

Comment: After LoginActivity starts Home again, why don't you immediately `finish()` the LoginActivity too, just like you did with the Home activity? Why is `android:noHistory` a better approach here?

Comment: Good question skrebbel :) Please, could you reason your solution or post differences between `noHistory` and `finish()` approach?

Comment: @skrebbel plz look at my comment to the answer by Jason-Robinson.

Comment: It may be too late. However, could you please offer more detailed source code? That would be great to the beginners like me. For example, how to handle the intent `android.intent.action.MAIN`? In which method, does the Home activity check if the user is signed in or not?

Comment: I have found an article called [Android User Session Management using Shared Preferences](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/), which basically share the same idea with yours, containing full source code.

Comment: One problem with noHistory is that once the next activity is added to the stack, the noHistory activity may be destroyed. (It will likely be at that point.)  The activity isn't merely skipped over when the user hits the back button...it's pre-emptively destroyed.  So, if your Login activity has a Privacy Policy or something else that might push on to the back stack, your Login pag might go away.

Comment: In your MainActivity to check if the user is logged in  private boolean userLoggedIn() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
        sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MainApplication.APP_SHARED_PREFS, instance().MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPrefs.getBoolean("userLoggedInState", false);
    }

Comment: Why is the approach better than turning the login activity into the Launcher Activity and then on the login activity check if the user is logged on or not?

Comment: If, for example, your application has multiple activities that could be started by other applications, it helps to know which one to go to. If the first action you come to is a login screen, you need to somehow figure out where the original intent was trying to go. If you have the target action itself trigger login, you can also tell your application which page to go to next on successful login.

Answer (score 22):

After you call `startActivity(...)` in the LoginScreen activity, call `finish()`. This will remove that activity from the activity stack, so pressing back will essentially close your app once you're in your Home activity.

Comment: If I do that then when, for any reason, my app goes in to background like when I press home screen, then pressing my apps icon from main screen will again show the login activity which will be added on top of Home activity in the stack.

Comment: Then you need to check in the `onCreate(...)` of the LoginScreen if you have the sufficient data to move on, and if so, start the Home activity. If not, wait for the user to log in. You can do this with `SharedPreferences` if you need something simple.

Answer (score 1):

> Try setting flags to the Intent.

**Example:**

```
new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

---

More information on flags:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#nestedclasses

Answer (score 1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41290453/4560689 (text below)

To do this, you should create a single launcher activity with No Display (using Android's NoDisplay theme), that runs the logic of whether to go to the home screen or to log in/register.

First, in your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.android">

<-- Permissions etc -->

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity
        android:name=".onboarding.StartupActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />

    <activity
        android:name=".authentication.controller.AuthenticationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_sign_in"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />

    <-- Other activities, services, etc -->
</application>
```

Then, your StartupActivity:

```
package com.example.android.onboarding;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.android.MainActivity;

import com.example.android.authentication.controller.AuthenticationActivity;

import com.example.android.util.ResourceUtils;

public class StartupActivity extends Activity {
    private static final AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent startupIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(startupIntent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent startupIntent = new Intent(this, AuthenticationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(startupIntent, AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private boolean isLoggedIn() {
        // Check SharedPreferences or wherever you store login information
        return this.getSharedPreferences("my_app_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("loggedIn", false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent startupIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(startupIntent);
        }

        finish();
    }
}
```

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/chanakin/c44bf1c6a9a80d2640440b5aaa92c8ee

Answer (score 1):

LoginActivity.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#263238">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <!-- App Logo -->
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!--Title TextView-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="STOCK BUDDY"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#7B869B"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <!--User Email-->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_email"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
            android:textColor="#7B869B"
            android:maxLength="40"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextshape"/>

        <!-- User Password -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textColor="#7B869B"
            android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextshape"/>

        <!--Login Button-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:onClick="Login"/>

        <!--signup Link TextView-->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="No account yet? Create one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#7B869B"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**`buttonshape.xml`**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="44dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:centerColor="#63D0C3"
        android:startColor="#70DB9A"
        android:endColor="#56C5EE"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="0dp"
        android:color="#878787"
        />
</shape>
```

edittextshape.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:thickness="0dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="44dp" />
</shape>
```

.....................

please see full code on
https://androidpugnator.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/android-login-and-signup-screens

[Image of login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVBRJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Call **startActivity(...)** in the LoginActivity on some event(say login button click  ).  Use a separate  database class also to store username and password of user from HomeActivity class.

Handle the **onKeyDown()** event for controlling back button in HomeActivity(use **finish()** method).

In **OnCreate()** method of LoginActivity class use database connection to check whether the username & password already exist in the database table if yes then call **startActivity()** there too to directly go to HomeScreen from LoginScreen.This will not show the LoginScreen.

Hope this will work for you.
Try it.