# Android Application which requires user to login first

Tags: android

I am developing an application which requires user to login before accessing any functionalities. Currently the login page is a standalone activity. I would like to ask which activity should I place as the MAIN of my application, the login activity or application activity (the first activity after login). In either way, there is a situation that I need to finish the current activity and start the other one (e.g. When application activity is the MAIN, when user didn't login before, I need to manually finish the application activity and start the login activity. I am not sure if it is a good approach because the first activity was started with nothing done). What is the best practice for login application like this?

P.S. I saw Skype will first show a Splash Screen before the login activity. The login state can be determined in the Splash Screen activity and start the subsequent one (login or application) accordingly. But I am not likely to take this if there is other good approach because an extra splash screen is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would one design a flow where one of the screens is a login screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126406/how-would-one-design-a-flow-where-one-of-the-screens-is-a-login-screen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter and depends on your application model. Using `finish()` on an Activity is quite acceptable.

I would say if you have a short time-out on the 'logged in' session, then you will likely need to use the login activity quite regularly and set it as the MAIN activity.

If the login credentials are to be cached for a long period of time (or indefinitely) then set the other activity as the MAIN one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my application, the login session will be expired after some time. I would like to ask how should the activities stack be handled when I start the login activity. If it isn't cleared, the activities will be shown again when the user presses "Back". However, the last activity cannot be resumed after user logged in if the stack is cleared. How to handle this case properly?

Comment: @pinglamb: That was my point about using finish(). Whichever activity you start first can easily start the other and finish() itself.

Comment: My follow up questions might be a little bit out of the scope. In my application, there are multiple entry points (e.g. activity for LAUNCHER, activity for Intent actions) and all required user to login first. Therefore finish the original activity and start the login one might not be good enough because I need to determine which activity to "restart" again after user logged in. One possible solution I can think of is keep the original activity and start the login screen on top, then implement the onResume() method to ensure user is logged in. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @pinglamb: As you say, keeping track of which activity to restart will be a problem. I agree, simply starting the login activity to appear in front of current activity then have the login activity finish() itself to return to that activity seems like the best approach. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Splash Screens are good. They make your app look and feel good :-)

Aesthetics aside splash screens are a single instance activity that does not require a lot of complexity and allows you do do the exact thing you want : switch activities based on some condition , in your case if the user is logged in or not.

This also simplifies your login and main activities as you no longer need to check login in state in these activities as you would have to if there was no splash screen.